# Call other functions inside of Javascript function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, function, model-view-controller

I'm having a problem and I feel like I am losing my mind over it. I am attempting to call on Javascript functions on a button click in an asp.net MVC project. My fuction on button click is this...

```
    // This function calls all functions needed on click of Problem card
    function CardButtonClick() {
        ChangeColors();
        HideForSelectionsToBeMade();
        ShowGradeAndWorkOrder();
        AddToListOfDropDownSelections();
    }
```

For some reason this is working but it is not running AddToListOfDropDownSelections(), I have changed the function where it is simply just an alert like this...

```
    // This function adds the values of the dropdown list selections to ListOfDropDownSelections for user view
    function AddToListOfDropDownSelections() {
            alert("test");
    }
```

Does anyone know why the other functions would run and not this one?

Comment: Look in the browser console (F12 or Ctrl+Shift+I or Cmd+Shift+I). Probably, one of the previous functions is throwing an error. If that's not it, switch to the "Sources" or "Debugging" tab, find your `CardButtonClick` function, and put a breakpoint on the first statement. Click so that you hit the breakpoint, and step through with the debugger to find out what's going wrong (perhaps you have another copy of that function that's overriding the one you've changed?).

Comment: You're right. I have an error in my ChangeColors() function. Trying to work that at now! Thanks for the help. I'm new to this and didn't know about the debugging tab.

Comment: The debugging tab is definitely your friend, as is keeping an eye on the console for errors. I see a lot of people write JavaScript in Visual Studio. Then they run it in the browser and something goes wrong, but they don't know to check the browser's dev tools to see what went wrong. They end up making changes to their code without understanding what's going on. And this is professional developers I'm talking about! So understanding where to go to check for errors is vital, in any language/framework.